.NET 8 Blazor with Microsoft Identity - Current User's Custom Properties
How do I get the current signed in user's custom properties that I have added? (Additional columns) I have done research but do not get answers on it. If I could get the user id I could perhaps write custom code for it.

How did you add custom properties? Is there any article we can reference?

I watched this video:https://youtu.be/tNzSuwV62Lw?si=xWQEt-LbSeXD6Hpq

Following code get current login user's name , and then find this user all information.
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManger

@code{
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync(){
        var state=await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var username = state.User.Identity.Name;
        var userFullinfo =await _userManger.FindByNameAsync(username);
    }
}

